# Unreliable behaviour of GTK function gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell()

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I need some help understanding why a bug is happening in some code using a GtkTreeView, and how to fix it.

In the program, the user opens an image and runs a function to detect stars in the image. This is all reliable and works fine. Data about each star is populated into a GtkTreeView.

The user then clicks on a star in the display which triggers a callback:

```
gboolean on_drawingarea_button_release_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
```

that in turn calls the function shown below:

```
void set_iter_of_clicked_psf(double x, double y) {
    GtkTreeSelection *selection = GTK_TREE_SELECTION(gtk_builder_get_object(gui.builder, "treeview-selection"));
    GtkTreeView *treeview = GTK_TREE_VIEW(lookup_widget("Stars_stored"));
    GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    gboolean valid;
    gboolean is_as;
    const double radian_conversion = ((3600.0 * 180.0) / M_PI) / 1.0E3;
    double invpixscalex = 1.0;
    double bin_X = gfit.unbinned ? (double) gfit.binning_x : 1.0;
    if (com.stars && com.stars[0]) {// If the first star has units of arcsec, all should have
        is_as = (strcmp(com.stars[0]->units,"px"));
    } else {
        return; // If com.stars is empty there is no point carrying on
    }
    if (is_as) {
        invpixscalex = 1.0 / (radian_conversion * (double) gfit.pixel_size_x / gfit.focal_length) * bin_X;
    }
    valid = gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(model, &iter);
    while (valid) {
        gdouble xpos, ypos, fwhmx;
        gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, COLUMN_X0, &xpos, -1);
        gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, COLUMN_Y0, &ypos, -1);
        gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, COLUMN_FWHMX, &fwhmx, -1);
        fwhmx *= invpixscalex;
        gdouble distsq = (xpos - x) * (xpos - x) + (ypos - y) * (ypos - y);
        gdouble psflimsq = 6. * fwhmx * fwhmx;
        if (distsq < psflimsq) {
            GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_model_get_path(model, &iter);
            if (!path) return;
            gtk_tree_selection_select_path(selection, path);
            gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell(treeview, path, NULL, TRUE, 0.5, 0.0);
            gtk_tree_path_free(path);
            gui.selected_star = get_index_of_selected_star(xpos, ypos);
            display_status();
            redraw(REDRAW_OVERLAY);
            return;
        }
        valid = gtk_tree_model_iter_next(model, &iter);
    }
    siril_debug_print("Point clicked does not correspond to a known star\n");
    return;
}
```

The code steps through each iter in the GtkTreeView and checks whether the location clicked is close enough to the centre of a star: the key bit of the code then follows inside the conditional towards the end of the function. If the location matches a star, a GtkTreePath is declared and initialised based on the iter, changes the selection to that path and calls gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell() which is supposed to scroll the GtkTreeView so that the selected star is shown.

For some users the code works every time and causes the tree view to scroll to the selected star. For other users sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work. When it doesn't work I can tell the correct code path is followed because gui.selected_star is updated correctly (it triggers a drawing event in the subsequent redraw(REDRAW_OVERLAY) call. It is only gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell() that appears to function erractically.

Neither I nor one of my fellow developers can see why it works sometimes but not always, nor can we see why some users don't see the bug at all. So if any GTK gurus could enlighten me I'd be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this strange bug at times. I have noticed this bug can also occur if a modal dialog is opened and closed before trying to preform the scrolling and the modal is not destroyed. Treeview scrolling messages are affected as a result. This leads me to believe some functions or callbacks may interfere with scrolling and those that interfere must finish all their message pump processing before the scrolling function can be called.

To sum up I believe the issue is the Gtk event loop (or message loop as windows users may call it)

One of the workaround solutions below I suspect may solve your issue. They have solved my issues in the past.

Solution 1)
If a modal dialog was opened before the scrolling event and not destroyed before scrolling. avoid opening the modal dialog before calling gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell()

Solution 2)
If you must use a modal dialog before a scrolling event, destroy the modal dialog before calling gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell().

Solution 3)
Set a timer for gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell() to be called later. This allows the message pump to finish process pending messages (that may be a result of the function you are currently in) that need to be handled before scrolling can occur. 500ms timer worked well for one of my programs.

Solution 4)
if a modal dialog cannot be destroyed yet, or you are in a function that is causing this issue. Ensure any modal is no longer in control of the message loop, and nothing else is in control of the message loop other than main. Then process pending messages BEFORE calling gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell(), code is below for processing pending messages.

`/*process pending messages*/ while(gtk_events_pending()){gtk_main_iteration();}`

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at those workarounds and see if any of them can fix my issue.

Comment: I've not tried the timer suggestion, but the 4th option which ought to force the same result of emptying the message queue doesn't work for me. I added some test code and I can see the event queue clearing down, but the users who experience the issue report no change in the behaviour of the GtkTreeView. I think there's a difference though: your fixes related to use of a modal dialog, whereas I'm not using any modal dialogs. I guess my search for a solution goes on but thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: The solution that was suggested to me is using `gdk_threads_add_idle` and pack the scrolling into the callback. That was indeed the solution in my case and I think this is a more reliable and less hacky solution than a timer.